# convert a .NET float[] to MATLAB matrix

Tags: .net, matlab

I've got a script in MATLAB that uses a .NET assembly I developed, which is passing `float[]` arrays, which appear in MATLAB as structs of type `1x1 Single[]` in the workspace window. At least I think it is a struct, I cannot find documentation on this. It's the icon showing a cube in the workspace view.

Now I could prepare a matrix of adequate size, iterate through my array and copy value-by-value, but the arrays may be quite big. I'm sure there is a more efficient way to accomplish what I want to do. Is there?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out: from the example [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-arrays-with-net-applications.html) I inferred that I can just typecast with `double( myFloatArray )`, which is so simple it was not obvious to me as a MATLAB n00b.